# Deciding which type of array to use

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to java programming as well as object programming as a whole, I have become stumped on which type of array to use.

I need to create an array that accepts user input for both a NAME and a PRICE and stores it in the array. I tried making two separate arrays and using a counter but it doesn't suit my needs. The problem lies with the issue that I need to be able to average the PRICE separately as well as reverse the array and filter the array if a specific name is entered. I also tried creating a object array and I wasn't sure if that was suitable.

Here is my code:

```
String names[] = new String[100]; // sets array size to almost ulimited #
            double prices[] = new double[100]; // sets array size to almost unlimited #
            double average = 0; // initializes the array 
            int count = 0; // initializes the count for the arraysize
            boolean flag = false;// initializes flag to false so it can be changed later


            while(true){
           System.out.print("Enter item " + (count + 1) + " name: "); // enter name
           names[count] = in.next(); // next string becomes count index
           if(names[count].equals("-1")){ break;} // if the next name entered is sentinel break
           System.out.print("Enter item " + (count + 1) + " price: "); // enter price
           prices[count] = in.nextDouble(); // stores price entered as array index
            // if next price == -1 then the program ends
           if(names[count].equalsIgnoreCase("peas")) flag = true;
           average += prices[count];
           count++;

       }
            System.out.println("The items and their prices are: ");
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
           System.out.println(names[i] + ": " + formatter.format(prices[i]));
       }
            average /= count;
            if(flag == true){
           System.out.println("Average: " + formatter.format(average));
       }
            else{
                System.out.println("no average output");
       }
```

I'm not necessarily looking for someone to do this for me or anything like that, I'm simply stumped and am looking for which way my logic should be thinking toward. Thank you everyone in advance!

Comment: `I need to be able to average the PRICE separately` ... what does this mean?  Does your code actually have a problem or are you just looking for a code review?

Comment: Sorry if that was confusing, basically I need to be able to store the price and name in a single array, BUT be able to average the price via a method. I tried storing it in an object array and couldn't average the price from the object array.

Comment: Why array? you can use a Map<String, Double>

Comment: Or if you just want to use arrays, you can use 2D array like {{"item1",123},{"item2",345}}

Comment: @AnilAgrawal for the java course I'm taking we're supposed to have a full grasp on arrays. To be honest, I haven't learned Maps yet.

Comment: Map is relatively easy to use and have no overhead. Its that simple as arrays, even more. just go through this link http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/ If you want to preserve the insertion order as well, you can use LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap

Comment: Thank you, I will read up on Maps now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your loops are basically good just few things that i did to make it work.
-put it all in one loop
-get rid of "if average is true" the averages are correct just somehow considered false

```
    String names[] = new String[5]; // sets array size to almost unlimited #
            double prices[] = new double[100]; // sets array size to almost unlimited #
            double average = 0; // initializes the array 
            int count = 0; // initializes the count for the arraysize
            boolean flag = false;// initializes flag to false so it can be changed later


            while(true){
           System.out.print("Enter item " + (count + 1) + " name: "); // enter name
           names[count] = System.console().readLine();//in.next(); // next string becomes count index
           if(names[count].equals("-1")){ break;} // if the next name entered is sentinel break
           System.out.print("Enter item " + (count + 1) + " price: "); // enter price
           prices[count] = Double.valueOf(System.console().readLine());//in.nextDouble(); // stores price entered as array index
            // if next price == -1 then the program ends
           if(names[count].equalsIgnoreCase("peas")) flag = true;
           average += prices[count];
           count++;
//     }//deleted

            System.out.println("The items and their prices are: ");
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
           System.out.println(names[i] + ": " + prices[i]);//formatter.format()
//     }//deleted
            average /= count;
            //if(flag == true){
           System.out.println("Average: " + average);//formatter.format()
       //}
            else{
                System.out.println("no average output");
       }//added
       }//added
       }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try this.

Answer (score 4):

First it is better you make one class which has `Name` and `Price` field.

```
public class Product {
    String name, price;

    //Getter and Setter
    // You can also define some other methods here as well.
}
```

Now create `ArrayList` of that class.

```
ArrayList<Product> myProduct = new ArrayList();
```

and do all the process on this arraylist.

Comment: Thank you, this is just the portion from my test class. I haven't really used arrayLists but I will research on them now. Thanks again.